# Pass a list in jstl param from jsp to another jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have one Bean which has two lists, I pass this bean as a modelAttribute to one jsp and I want to pass one of the list of the bean to another jsp. Currently I am doing this:

```
    <c:import url="jsp2" charEncoding="UTF-8">
        <c:param name="list" value="${bean.list}"/>
    </c:import>
```

But in the jsp2 is not working properly, somebody knows if a list can be passed from one jsp to another jsp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need not pass it from one jsp to another. You can store it in your **session** variable.

Before you invoke your view page (your jsp), you should set two session variables, one for each of your maps:

request.getSession().setAttribute("nameOfYourFirstMap", firstMap);
request.getSession().setAttribute("nameOfYourSecondMap", secondMap);

Then, you will be able to access your map from any jsp, using EL:

`${nameOfYourFirstMap}` for the first, or
`${nameOfYourSecondMap}` for the second.

Give it a run and see if it solves your prob.